# Is $w$ a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $W$ be the set of all solutions$(X,y,i,r)$ such that $a+b=m^2$. is $w$ a vector space?
Can anybody do the whole thing for me and explain shortly every step? I have to do this kind of lots of question today.

Comment: Where is $n$ in $a+b=m^2$?

Comment: @Riccardo.Alestra : I don't think it has to be there. It's just the set of vectors in $\mathbb R^4$ such that there is a constraint on three of the four components, that's it.

Comment: *Do not deface your question*.

Comment: I want to delete my account and question as i didnot get the right answer

Comment: @titt You can delete your account by following [these steps](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/user-deletion). But you cannot delete your posts; you already gave the site a permission to publish them.

Comment: u guy cheated with me . i own the questions

Comment: @damnu You don't "own" the questions. This is a community owned and community supported site.

Comment: It's "i owns" or "questionz".   Practice the style before taking it live.

Answer (score 4):

It is not a vector space. Intuitively, since in a vector space everything happens linearly, you should be 'scared' of the square and think of a counter example. Here is one. The vectors
$$
(4,0,0,2), (0,0,4,2)
$$
are in your space, because $4 + 0 = 2^2$ and $0 + 4 = 2^2$. But the sum of those two vectors are $(4,0,4,4)$ and $4+4 = 8 \neq 16 = 4^2$. Therefore your space $W$ is not closed under addition, hence not a vector space.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Typo: You meant to write $4 + 4 = 8 \neq 16 = 4^2$.

Comment: @Bryan : Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Two answers have already shown that your $W$ is not a vector space because it's not closed under addition.  It seems easier to reach the same conclusion by showing it's not closed under multiplication by scalars, say by $2$, or by $-1$.